# Animation a Silverlight UI element width from 0 to auto, smoothly

Tags: silverlight, animation

I have a Silverlight UI with a slide-out panel. When a button is clicked, I'd like the panel to animate out smoothly, with the width going from 0 to Auto. Is there a way to do this (ideally with pure XAML)?

Comment: The problem with auto is that its value is double.NaN, so I don't think you can animate to that in a linear way. You'd have to calculate the auto's current value (hard to do from pure XAML), and animate to that, then set to auto discreetly.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible- Auto uses the built-in sizing mechanisms in Silverlight.  I think you can only animate between definitive values, eg 0 to 300.

Comment: @Dave: You can use binding in the To property of an animation in SL4

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to animate Auto values, but as a workaround you can use `VisualStateManager` and `FluidLayout` with the following steps:
- Add a state group in Expression Blend
- Add the initial state
- Add the final state
- Change the visisbility to Collapsed in Blend
- Enable FluidLayout
- Write code to switch between states
- This will animate both width, height, and opacity of the element while showing it using a custom `VisualStateManager`
- You can write your own custom state manager to control the transition between discrete states

Answer (score 2):

why dont you just animate the maxwidth? Dont think you'll be able to animate to auto

Answer (score 1):

WOW that really made me think :) but I believe that I found a workaround that you can use. You will need a Converter but it's the only code you need in C# - the rest is in pure XAML.

I have reconstructed some XAML based on your input:

```
<Grid
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Background="Lime"
    x:Name="m_Grid">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform
            TranslateX="{Binding ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource InverseTranslateXConverter}, ElementName=m_Grid}" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Button
        x:Name="m_Button"
        Margin="50"
        Content="Hello World" />
</Grid>
```

So what I do is actually is just to wrap the slider inside a grid and set the TranslateX property to the ActualWidth of the content * -1 (done using a converter):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    double d = 0;
    if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d))
    {
        return d * -1;
    }

    return value;
}
```

To show it (slide in) I use a simple animation:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Storyboard
    x:Name="Storyboard1">
    <DoubleAnimation
        x:Name="m_Animation"
        Duration="0:0:0.2"
        To="0"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
        Storyboard.TargetName="m_Grid"
        d:IsOptimized="True" />
</Storyboard>
```

It's not pretty but it works :)

[EDIT] Just removed the outergrid - it was unnessesary.